# Passing a svg file as a prop in React (Gatsby) and still use SVGR & SVG as a component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have a 'static' component that works fine in isolation and optimises and inlines the SVG using SVGR/SVGO

```
import React from "react"
import { ReactComponent as Illustration } from "../assets/some_image.svg"

const Feature = props => {
    return (
        <Illustration />
    )
}

export default Feature
```

However, I now need to make this dynamic and pass the svg file in via a prop.

Pseudo code below (I know this will error as Import cant be within a function)

```
import React from "react"

const Feature = props => {
    import { ReactComponent as Illustration } from {props.svg}
    return (
        <Illustration />
    )
}

export default Feature
```

I am banging my head, there must be some way to do this?

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: I guess since you have the path `props.svg`, why not import in the parent component and directly pass the `<Illustration />` as a props? Refer to https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with importing the component at the top of the file, then passing it as props. Is there a reason you're not doing this?